# Как правильно передавать флаги компиляции в cmake?

Tags: cmake

Как правильно передать параметры компиляции в `cmake`? Через `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` или через `target_compile_options`? 
Кое где написано что нужно использовать `target_compile_options`, но если мне нужны свои типы сборок со своими флагами документация предлагает использовать `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_<CONFIG>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Понятие «правильно» здесь не применимо. Переменные типа `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_<CONFIG>` являются глобальными для всего проекта (это важно только в том случае, когда проектов несколько в одном большом). `target_compile_options` применяется только к одному проекту (цели).

Соответственно и выбирать стоит исходя из потребностей: если не нужны глобальные флаги, лучше выбирать более локальное решение (т.е. `target_compile_options`). Но это не более «правильное» решение, просто рекомендуемое.